# How to validate brackets '((()))''?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I had a problem on my last interview with the next task:

Make the function that will validate the count of the brackets and if each opens bracket will have the close bracket (like `()` or `(((())))`) - the validation must be `true`, in other way (like `((` or `)(` or `()()))`) - must be `false`.

I mean that the count of open brackets must equal to the count of close brackets.

If some one can explain me how it must work I'll be happy. Thanks!

```
function validator(brackets) {
  ...// some code
} 

const goodBrackets = '(((())))';
const badBrackets = '(()())))';
const veryBadBrackets = '(()())()))';

validator(goodBrackets);
validator(badBrackets);
validator(veryBadBrackets);
```

Comment: That won't work for: `())(` @MatthiasHerrmann

Comment: Are these ok? `(()())()` and these `(()()())`

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with the `veryBadBrackets`, all brackets are enclosed, what rules do you have? And probably what most down voters are asking, what have you tried?

Comment: Just use a counter of unmatched open parenthesis, make sure it doesn't go below 0 and that it will be 0 at the end.

Comment: @Icepickle I mean that the count of open brackets must equal to the count of close brackets.

Comment: Yes, but the `veryBadBrackets` checks out, it has exactly the same opening as closing brackets, so there is nothing wrong with it there

Comment: @Icepickle yes, You right. Updated my question

Comment: @MaxWolfen if that's the only rule then `)(` would have to be valid.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be done using stack, but this is not necessary (extra memory). To check the balance, you will need only a counter which will be incremented in case of `(` and decremented if encounter any `)`. At any point if you encounter an `)` and the counter is less than 1, that means you don't have any `(` to match current right parenthesis. So its not valid. At the end, if counter is 0 meaning the expression is balanced.

I don't know javascript, this is some sort of pseudocode:

```
function validator(string expression) {
    count := 0
    for (int i = 0; i < expression.length; i++):
        if (expression[i] == '('):
            count++
        else if (expression[i] == ')'):
            if (count == 0):
                return false
            else:
                count--
    end //for

    if (count == 0):
        return true
    
    return false
}
```

Comment: That's a weird pseudo language where `for` blocks need an `end` but `if`/`else` blocks don't :-)

Comment: You're right. Just edited, hope the OP will get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways you can check for `valid braces`.

```
validator=B=>(X=B.replace(/\(\)|\[]|{}|<>/,''))==B?!B:validator(X)
```

Recursive. (will provide an explanation in a bit). Checks for all brackets `()/[]/{}/<>`

## Explanation :

```
validator = Bracket => {          // define the function and parameter Bracket
  X = Bracket.replace(/\(\)|\[]|{}|<>/,'') // replace all of these with empty strings
  return X == B ? !B : validator(X) // if empty string then !B is returned (guess what that is
        // other wise repeat with X as input
```

---

Another one is far simpler :

```
Validator = (braces) => { // define function and parameter braces
    while(/\(\)|\[\]|\{\}/g.test(braces)){ // while there are still any of these left
        braces = braces.replace(/\(\)|\[\]|\{\}/g,"") // keep replacing with ''
    }
    return !braces.length; // return the opposite of brace.length after that 
    // 0 becomes 1 and 1 becomes 0
}
```

---

Another answer : (I think beats my first one for being overly weird)

```
Validator = (b, X) => {
    for(; (X= b.replace(/\[\]|\{\}|\(\)/, '')) != b; b = X);
    return!X
}
```

---

## Lengthy explanation :

This is the lengthy explanation for the first method for validating brackets :

```
/** 
    define function brackets 
    @param {string} brackets to test
**/
const Validator = (brackets) => {
    // create a variable check 
    let check = brackets.replace(
        /                         // start regexp 
        \(\)                      // Check for parenthesis ( and )
        |                         // OR 
        \[]                       // Check for square brackets [ and ]
        |                         // OR
        {}                        // Check for brackets { and }
        |                         // OR
        <>                        // Check for < and > 
        /                         // end regexp 
        ,                         // replace all this with 
        ''                        // empty string 
        )                         // end replace
// check if check is equal to brackets
if (check === brackets) {
    // if so then return the inverse of bracket 
    return !brackets
}
// otherwise 
return Validator(check); // otherwise set the parameter equal to check and repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a status variable that is initially set to 0.

Create a loop that looks at the characters in the string from beginning to end.

Inside the loop, first check the character. If it is '(', increase the status variable. If it is ')', decrease the status variable.

If the status variable becomes negative, the expression is invalid and you may exit.

If the status variable is 0 again after the loop finishes, the expression is valid.

I leave the coding up to you. ;)

Edit: veryBadBrackets might be correct. Depends on the kind of expression, of course. `((A OR B) AND (C OR D)) OR (E AND (F OR G))` might be such an expression. Nothing wrong with it.

Edit 2: Ah. veryBadBrakets now has more closing brackets than opening brackets... Then it will correctly fail.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function validate(input) {
  let tmp = 0;
  for (c of input) {
    if (c === '(') tmp++;
    else if (c === ')' && --tmp < 0) return false; // Unexpected  ')' 
  }
  return tmp === 0; // False if unbalanced
}

const goodBrackets = '(((())))';
const badBrackets = '(()())))';
const veryBadBrackets = '(()())()))';

console.log(validate(goodBrackets));
console.log(validate(badBrackets));
console.log(validate(veryBadBrackets));
```

Comment: This would work indeed. This was my initial solution too. However, Kaidul Islam's pseudocode is somewhat more optimized. Checking for the negative counter value (tmp in your case) only needs to be done in case of a closing bracket. And checking if the counter (tmp) is zero before decreasing it spares a decrease operation. ;)

Comment: @BartHofland "This would work" , wouldn't that warrant an upvote? Also, optimizing away a singe check / assignment is hardly necessary in js.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is test one item from each end of the string, looping till we get to the middle.

```js
const goodBrackets = '(((())))';
const badBrackets = '(()())))';
const veryBadBrackets = '(()())()';

function validate(b) {
  // make sure we have an even number of paren
  if (b % 2 == 0) return false
  // Split the items into an array
  let items = b.split('')
  // Test how many items to loop over
  let t = b.length / 2
  for (let i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    // Get the item from the begining
    let first = items[i]
    // Get the item form the other side
    let last = items[items.length - i - 1]
    // Test the two, they should not match to be valid
    // If they do match then return false
    if (first == last) return false
  }
  return true
}

console.log(validate(goodBrackets))
console.log(validate(badBrackets))
console.log(validate(veryBadBrackets))
```

Comment: `if (b % 2 == 0) return false` hmm, I guess it works but I'd still prefer to state as an assumption `Assuming the string only contains brackets`. The question doesn't clearly state if that would be the case - it simply says to validate the *brackets*. In theory, the input `(x + y) * z` could still be valid.

Comment: Assuming we are only testing parenthesis and nothing else this should work.

Comment: You don't have to turn the string into an array...

Comment: Also, I don't think it would work for this which should validate to true: `((())())`, but mine would validate it as false